# Missing Application Claims when completed SignUp policy on Azure B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am implementing the Azure B2C preview in our mobile app but I am having trouble retrieving the application claims once the Signup policy has completed and the redirect_uri is called.  I have specified the claims I need returned through the "Application claims" section of the policy blade and similarly through the other two policies (Sign-in and Profile) but I never receive a JWT along with the access code on the callback to the redirect_uri.

I have also tried HTTP and HTTPS in the redirect_uri and using the different response_mode settings but all i get is the code returned.

Am i missing something, or does the signup policy not support returning other claims at this point.  I was planning on using them to send a welcome email to the new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i may have just realised - i need to make a call to the token endpoint to swap my code for the id_token and then i can get the claims.